# Running ms sql local db express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I installed Microsoft SQL Server Express localDB. Now I want to run it, and according to this tutorial: 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/
I run (in cmd line):

```
SqlLocalDb info
```

then I get in cmd line: `SqlLocalDb is not recognized as an internal or external command`

How to fix it? Probbaly I have to add somethink to PATH variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's strange that the installer didn't add it to your PATH already, but ignoring that - can you go to your C:\Program Files (might be in the x86 folder as well), find where the program was installed, and look for "SqlLocalDb.exe"? This is what would be executed when you run SqlLocalDb from the command line.

If you find it, open the command line at that location and try to run that command. (Tip: You can hold Shift and right click in the empty space in that window, and the right-click menu will contain "Open command window here".)

If that works, you can add that location to your PATH so that you don't have to be in that folder or specify the location.

Comment: No problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the reason was I had SQL Server Management Studio, but I didn´t have installed the SQL Server.

I downloaded it from the Microsoft website and worked just fine. This is the Spanish version: https://www.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Answer (score -1):

restart your computer, it worked like that for me.

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue and installing **Microsoft SQL Server Express Localdb** seemed to have fixed it.
Tutorial here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5612/getting-started-with-sql-server-2017-express-localdb/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32601667)